# Django form validation don't function

Tags: javascript, html, django, validation, django-forms

I try to put validations in my form but after I follow the official documentation and tutorials I don't obtain the solution.
This is my code:
(The variables of class are indented)

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'},
                          choices=SUBJECTS_SELE),
                          label='Materia')
question = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                           label='Pregunta',
                           max_length=5000)
answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                         label='Respuesta correcta',
                         max_length=1000)
answerOne = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                            label='Respuesta incorrecta',
                            max_length=1000,
                            required=True)

def clean_question(self):
     question = self.cleaned_data.get('question')
     a = "0"
     if not a in question:
         raise forms.ValidationError("Es obligatorio llenar este campo")
     return question


def clean_answer(self):
     answer = self.cleaned_data.get('answer')
     a = "0"
     if not a in answer:
         raise forms.ValidationError("Es obligatorio llenar este campo")
     return answer
```

Also I have try this way:

```
def clean(self, *args, **kwargs):
        question = self.cleaned_data.get('question')
        answer = self.cleaned_data.get('answer')
        if question != "0":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Es obligatorio llenar este campo")
        if answer != "0":
            raise forms.ValidationError("Es obligatorio llenar este campo")
        return super(QuestionForm, self).clean(*args, **kwargs)
```

In this case the view corresponding to this form is the following one:

```
def ayudanos(request):
    form = QuestionForm(request.POST or None)
    if form.is_valid():
        form_data = form.cleaned_data
        subject = form_data.get("subject")
        question = form_data.get("question")
        answer = form_data.get("answer")
        answerOne = form_data.get("answerOne")
        answerTwo = form_data.get("answerTwo")
        name = form_data.get("name")
        obj = QuestionSele.objects.create(subject=subject, question=question, answer=answer, answerOne=answerOne,
                                          answerTwo=answerTwo, name=name)
    context = {
        "form": form
    }
    return render(request, "ayudanos.html", context)
```

Where the variables passed to the object is for save in a BBDD.

ACTUALIZED--------------------

After try the options people recommended my in the comments, I didn't see the validation message, and the moment I have remove the part of code which reload page after doing the form I could see the validation message.

my html and JavaScript:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
        {% if form %}
        <form action="" method="POST" id="askFortm"> {% csrf_token %}
          {{ form.as_p }}
          <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary enviar" id="enviar" type="submit" value="Enviar">Introducir otra
              pregunta</button>
          </form>
          {% endif %}
    </div>

<script>
    
    $(function() {
        var counter = 94;
        $( "#enviar" ).click(function() {
            counter = counter + 1;
                //alert(counter);
                localStorage.setItem("counter",counter);
                alert('Su pregunta ha sido enviada correctamente. ' +
                    'Envía otra y tendras más posibilidades de ganar los Airpods.');
            });
        $('#askFortm').on('submit', function(e) {
              e.preventDefault();
              setTimeout(function() {
                   window.location.reload();
              },0);
              this.submit();
        });
    });
    
    </script>
```

I suppose that the problem can be relation with the reload page,  is possible I have to compare the csrf_token or something like this?
Can you help me, thanks.

Comment: Now, it actualized my comment with the view of this form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I have solve this putting an HttpResponseRedirect in my views:

```
def ayudanos(request):
form = QuestionForm(request.POST or None)
if form.is_valid():
    form_data = form.cleaned_data
    subject = form_data.get("subject")
    question = form_data.get("question")
    answer = form_data.get("answer")
    answerOne = form_data.get("answerOne")
    answerTwo = form_data.get("answerTwo")
    name = form_data.get("name")
    email = form_data.get("email")
    obj = QuestionSele.objects.create(subject=subject, question=question, answer=answer, answerOne=answerOne,
                                      answerTwo=answerTwo, name=name, email=email)
    return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('ayudanos'))
context = {
    "form": form
}
return render(request, "ayudanos.html", context)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'},
                          choices=SUBJECTS_SELE),
                          label='Materia')
    question = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                           label='Pregunta',
                           max_length=5000)
    answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                         label='Respuesta correcta',
                         max_length=1000)
    answerOne = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                            label='Respuesta incorrecta',
                            max_length=1000,
                            required=True)

    def clean_question(self):
        question = self.cleaned_data.get('question')
        a = "0"
        if a not in question:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Es obligatorio llenar este campo")
        return question


    def clean_answer(self):
        answer = self.cleaned_data.get('answer')
        a = "0"
        if a not in answer:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Es obligatorio llenar este campo")
        return answer
```

Comment: Your code work correct but the problem is not here, the comment was actualized.

Answer (score 0):

I believe when the user did not give the value in the must field Question or answer, it will be empty , so below code should work.

```
class QuestionForm(forms.Form):
    subject = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select'},
                          choices=SUBJECTS_SELE),
                          label='Materia')
    question = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                           label='Pregunta',
                           max_length=5000)
    answer = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                         label='Respuesta correcta',
                         max_length=1000)
    answerOne = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'form-control', 'rows': 1}),
                            label='Respuesta incorrecta',
                            max_length=1000,
                            required=True)

    def clean_question(self):
        question = self.cleaned_data.get('question')

        if not question:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Es obligatorio llenar este campo")
        return question


    def clean_answer(self):
        answer = self.cleaned_data.get('answer')

        if not answer:
            raise forms.ValidationError("Es obligatorio llenar este campo")
        return answer
```

Comment: What kind of data is default to that field ?

Comment: Sorry, this code works nice how works my code and the code of the first comment, I'm comming edit the comment to explain the problem again since the problem is caused by javascript code part.

Comment: just one part, now the comment is actualized.